# Почему в Google Chrome появляется следующее предупреждение?

Tags: php, html, apache

Почему в Google Chrome появляется следующeе предупреждение, при скачкe файла с сервера?
Web-server - Apache

```
  Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

PHP:

```
$file = "uploads/demo.docx";
        //text/html; charset=UTF-8 - С этим заголовком предупреждений нету
        header ("Content-Type: application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=UTF-8");
        header ("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));  
        header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=demo.docx");  
        readfile($file);
```

Даже если мы просто укажим путь к файлу через HTML

```
<a href="http://server/uploads/demo.docx">Скачать</a>
```

то всё равно получим то-же предупреждение.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так 
`<a href="http://server/uploads/demo.docx" download>Скачать</a>`

Это проблема специфичная для chrome. Помню еще bug был связан с ним.

[Да вот этот](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9891) - корнями сюда доходит. Видимо еще не исправили.